# Why can't I type a value into my input field in IE11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have the following input fields that are displayed after toggling a dropdown menu:

**main.html**

```
    <ul class="dropdown-menu appExperience tileContextMenu">
          <li class ="gridster-form"
                role="form"
                aria-labeledby="Gridster Layout Form"
                alt="Tile Display Input column Input Row">
                <span class="dropdown-text">
                    Col <input type="text" value='tiledata.col' ng-model="tiledata.col" class="input-col">
                    Row <input type="text" value='tiledata.row' ng-model="tiledata.row" class="input-row">     
                    <i class= "fa fa-arrows"></i>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </span>
```

Here is my css stylesheet in case this could become useful

**style.css**

```
 .tileContextMenu:after
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 15px 15px;
border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
top: -15px;
left: 135px;
}

.tcm-chevron{
    color: white;
    padding-right: 10px;
    float:right;
}

.input-col {
   text-align: center;
   width:25px;
   height:25px;
}

.input-row {
   text-align: center;
   width:25px;
   height:25px;
}

.gridster-form {
   color: #000;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can fix the input field?

Comment: What do you mean "can't type into it"? Maybe an image of what you're seeing would help. Can you not even click into the field to type? Are you the author of the Angular aspects (`ng-model` etc) - maybe that's doing something.

Comment: Works fine for me -> https://jsfiddle.net/991suvfx/

Comment: @mmcrae I mean I can't click into the field to type. ng-model isn't the problem, it's doing exactly what it's supposed it.

Comment: @KO12 - the jsFiddle works. So there's something outside of the HTML/CSS you posted that's causing it. I would check if there's some other JS, after document load or similar, that's causing this.